# node.js killing a request early

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, request

In my app I'm downloading a file if I click on it thanks to http.get

```
var buffer = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
$('a').click(function(){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
             buffer.write(chunk);
```

and if I click on a second link, it will download it on the same buffer as well.

this doesn't work well and the two files get mixed.

- What I want is to kill the first request when I start the second one, any idea how to do this?
- Also I'm using **http.get**, but sometimes the module **request.get**, I don't see any differences, which one should I use for this job?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around with event emitters:

```
require('event')
```

just emit something, and catch it to kill the request with a res.destroy();

Comment: Please edit your original post, or add this as a comment to it.